# Path to EditorTemplates in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I tell the viewengine to look for editortemplates in another area that is in another web project?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581786/can-i-add-to-the-display-editortemplates-search-paths-in-asp-net-mvc-3 It talks about how you can add paths to the search locations for view engines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting full path to the template (~/Areas/YourArea/Views/...) in UIHintAttribute?

*Update:*

I assume the code (link in the comments below) comes from one application, while the actual template resides in a different application. IMHO this just won't work. You might want to google for sharing templates between applications but I think the only valid solution is not to share a template but add extension methods to HtmlHelper and share those.

Comment: @Marcus - Are you keeping your templates in the Shared folder?

Comment: I Have two different web projects so the template folders is not shared between the projects. The goal is to have a kinda dashboard project/area and I would like to use editortemplates from my main projects/area

Comment: @Marcus - so you should change your question - it's not about reusing templates from another area, but from another project!

Comment: Well I thought it did not matter because I register the area the way you should, but maybe asp.net works differently if the area is in the same project?

Comment: @Marcus - Could you post your RegisterRoute code - how do you register a route from another application?

Comment: This is from my global.asax http://codepaste.net/1f4r4o and this is my area registration http://codepaste.net/uca4ig

Comment: @Marcus - I assume the code comes from one application, while the actual template resides in a different application. IMHO this just won't work. You might want to google for sharing templates between applications but I think the only valid solution is not to share a template but add extension methods to HtmlHelper and share those.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the path when including the editor template:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProp, "~/areas/somearea/views/editortemplates/test.ascx") %>
```

Or use the [UIHint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute on the model property.

Comment: I use the UIHint attribute on my model but it seems like I must have my templates in main project?